# Authentication as CIA triad

Tags: authentication, integrity, confidentiality, availability

As we all know, information security principles are stated as CIA triad, i.e., confidentiality, integrity, and availability. I wonder why authentication is not a part of CIA triad as being an important factor in information security. Does it belong to another classification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CIA are the aspects of a system that information security strives to protect.  Authentication and authorization (important and distinct concepts) are security *controls* that are used to protect the system with regard to the CIA properties.  For example, authenticating a user and checking that they are authorized to access the data ensures the **confidentiality** of that data.  Authenticating and then authorizing for modification is helping to ensure **integrity** of the data.